# Session Time Out ASP MVC 4 Warning

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I want to create a session time out, i have edited the web.config file and add the time for the sessions end, but i need to show a warning before the session is over, this way the user can continue with his work.

Is there a way to know when the session is over, show the warning and redirect the user to the login page?

```
<sessionState timeout="1"></sessionState>
```

I'm using ASP MVC4.

Thanks!

Comment: which authentication mode are you using ?

Comment: I'm saving the user in a Session variable. The authentication mode for the user is by Active Directory.

Comment: A simple(ish) solution using JS can be found on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616634/ASP-NET-MVC-How-To-Show-A-Popup-Warning-Before-Ses). You should download the solution to read through it, as it includes DevExpress which is a paid technology that you may not have access to.